# Combining ggpubr functions ggsummarystats() and stat_compare_means() in R possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

recently I have become aware of the powerful ggpubr package and the ease to display plots while including statistical tests easily by adding stat_compare_means() to a ggline plot.

I wanted to bring my figures to perfection by adding stats below like number of participants per group and values for mean and maybe sd, which should be actually possible by using ggsummarystats().

However, if I nest my ggline arguments into ggsummarystats() and add stat_compare_means() below, R puts "NULL" out.

The following example works fine and shows basic stats below the graph, but doesn't include asterix for p values above.

```
df %>%
  ggsummarystats(x="TIMEPOINT",
         y="PROTEIN_CONCENTRATION",
         color="DISEASE",
         add=c("jitter", "mean_sd"),
         add.params = list(alpha=0.3),
         palette= "jco",
         ggfunc=ggline,
         summaries = c("n", "mean", "ci")
         )
```

If I add stat_compare_means() it doesn't work any longer -> "NULL"

```
df %>%
  ggsummarystats(x="TIMEPOINT",
         y="PROTEIN_CONCENTRATION",
         color="DISEASE",
         add=c("jitter", "mean_sd"),
         add.params = list(alpha=0.3),
         palette= "jco",
         ggfunc=ggline,
         summaries = c("n", "mean", "ci")
         )
stat_compare_means(aes(group = DISEASE), label = "p.signif", label.y = 40)
```

My gut feeling tells me, that I have to include the stat_compare_means() somehow into ggsummarystats like for the ggline function, but I don't know how.

Does anyone know how to combine asterix above the graph with basics stats below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object produced by `ggsummarystats` is essentially a list of two ggplots; one for the main plot called `main.plot` and one for the table, called `summary.plot`. You must add your `stat_compare_means` to `main.plot` and write it back in to the `ggsummarystats` object.

In the absence of a reproducible example, let's use the example from the `ggsummarystats` help file:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)

set.seed(123)
qc <- rep(c("pass", "fail"), 30)
df$qc <- as.factor(sample(qc, 60))

summary.stats <- df %>%
  group_by(dose) %>%
  get_summary_stats(type = "common")
```

Now we generate and store the plot:

```r
p <- ggsummarystats(
  df, x = "dose", y = "len",
  ggfunc = ggboxplot, add = "jitter",
  color = "dose", palette = "npg"
)
```

Now `p` looks like this:

```r
p
```

[image]

And we add a `stat_compare_means` layer to the `main.plot` member of `p` like this:

```
p$main.plot <- p$main.plot + 
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif",
                     comparisons = list(c("0.5", "1"),
                                        c("1",   "2"),
                                        c("0.5", "2")))
```

So that `p` becomes:

```r
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This works fine also for line plots! Is this also possible in one pipe (i.e. block of code) for easier use?